# Send drawing from a class to a form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

I have a class named `CircleSector` which draws a PIChart.

I am unable to draw the PIChart if I call the Class from `form1`.

Here is my code:

**Form1:**

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int textdata = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    CS = new CircleSector(textdata, this);
    // CS.GetGraphicSector(this);
}
```

**CircleSector:**

```
public CircleSector(int TextData , Form1 D)
{
    Pen CirclePen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    Rect = new Rectangle(XAxis, YAxis, CircleRadius, CircleRadius);
    float temp1 = 0;
    SectorCircle = this.CreateGraphics();
    PIVal = - 360 / TextData;

    float temp2 = PIVal;
    for (int i = 0; i <= TextData; i++)
    {
        m_Value = i;
        SectorCircle.DrawPie(CirclePen, Rect, 0, temp2);
        temp1 = temp2;
        temp2 = temp2 - PIVal;
    }

    //  MessageBox.Show("Mouse Pressed");
    //  return SectorCircle;
}
```

Comment: still getting problem?

Comment: Thank you. Problem was with this.CreateGraphics()

Comment: @user3458123 if you got the solution then don't forget to accept the answer? Accepting an answer will help to understand other people that which solution is best in this case.

Comment: You should also dispose SectorCircle after usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here.

```
SectorCircle = this.CreateGraphics();
```

try this.

```
SectorCircle = D.CreateGraphics();
```